# Compare column of one table to another and update in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have two tables for which I want to create a `Stored procedure`.

Table 1:- `R4G_APPDEV.plannedroute_evw` Table 2 :- `ASSIGNED_ROUTE_MASTER`

Now what I want is I want to compare some column from Table 2 with Table 1 and if there is any difference in the column values then update the column in Table 2.

Below are the Table description for both the tables.

Table 1:- R4G_APPDEV.plannedroute_evw

```
Name                        Null? Type            
--------------------------- ----- --------------- 
OBJECTID                          NUMBER          
MEASUREDLENGTH                    NUMBER(38,8)    
DEPTHPLACED                       NUMBER(38,8)    
HEIGHT                            NUMBER(38,8)    
WIDTH                             NUMBER(38,8)    
NUMBEROFDUCTS                     NUMBER(5)       
NUMBEROFSUBDUCTS                  NUMBER(5)       
DUCTDIAMETER                      NUMBER(38,8)    
SUBDUCTDIAMETER                   NUMBER(38,8)    
REMARKS                           NVARCHAR2(250)  
NETWORKTYPE                       NUMBER(10)      
NETWORKCATEGORY                   NVARCHAR2(50)   
ROUTENAME                         NVARCHAR2(200)  
FACILITYID                        NVARCHAR2(41)   
BWLEASE                           NVARCHAR2(50)   
ENABLED                           NUMBER(5)       
TRENCHMATERIAL                    NVARCHAR2(15)   
UNITS                             NVARCHAR2(5)    
AGGREGATEROUTENAME                NVARCHAR2(200)  
CSSROUTENAME                      NVARCHAR2(200)  
COREROUTENAME                     NVARCHAR2(200)  
PHASE                             NVARCHAR2(20)   
PATHID                            NVARCHAR2(30)   
AGGREGATEROUTE                    NVARCHAR2(50)   
OWNER                             NVARCHAR2(50)   
ACTUALLENGTH                      NUMBER(38,8)    
CITYCODE                          NVARCHAR2(4)    
CITYNAME                          NVARCHAR2(50)   
DUCTCOLOUR                        NVARCHAR2(50)   
REGULATORYDUCT                    NUMBER(5)       
ADDITIONALPROTECTIONREQD          NVARCHAR2(10)   
PROTECTIONTYPE                    NVARCHAR2(200)  
LINK_ID                           NVARCHAR2(25)   
SPAN_ID                           NVARCHAR2(25)   
OPERATOR_ID                       NVARCHAR2(50)   
CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY          NVARCHAR2(50)   
ROUTEPATH_NEW                     NVARCHAR2(200)  
ROUTETYPE                         NVARCHAR2(50)   
SWITH_ON_CORE                     NVARCHAR2(50)   
FINAL_CORE                        NVARCHAR2(50)   
SWITCH_ON_COLLECTOR               NVARCHAR2(50)   
FINAL_COLLECTOR                   NVARCHAR2(50)   
COLLECTOR_BW_CLASSIFICATION       NVARCHAR2(50)   
FROM_CITY                         NVARCHAR2(50)   
TO_CITY                           NVARCHAR2(50)   
PLANNEDDATE                       TIMESTAMP(6)    
USER_NAME                         NVARCHAR2(50)   
CREATED_USER                      NVARCHAR2(50)   
LAST_EDITED_USER                  NVARCHAR2(50)   
LAST_EDITED_DATE                  TIMESTAMP(6)    
CREATED_DATE                      TIMESTAMP(6)    
INTRACITY_LINK_ID                 NVARCHAR2(20)   
SRNO                              NUMBER(10)      
LEASE_ROUTE_NAME                  NVARCHAR2(200)  
R4G_STATE                         NVARCHAR2(50)   
LEASE_ROUTE_LINK_ID               NVARCHAR2(25)   
LEASE_ROUTE_SPAN_ID               NVARCHAR2(25)   
SCOPE_CATEGORY                    NVARCHAR2(25)   
INTRACITY_CONSTRUCTION_TYPE       NVARCHAR2(25)   
FACILITY_SAP_ID                   NVARCHAR2(25)   
NLD_STAGES                        NVARCHAR2(10)   
AG_PARENTID                       NVARCHAR2(30)   
CORE_PARENTID_1                   NVARCHAR2(30)   
CORE_PARENTID_2                   NVARCHAR2(30)   
SDCC_OBLIGATION                   NVARCHAR2(25)   
LASTMILE_ID                       NVARCHAR2(20)   
LINK_ID_100G                      NVARCHAR2(25)   
SPAN_ID_100G                      NVARCHAR2(25)   
LINK_ID_NX10G                     NVARCHAR2(25)   
SPAN_ID_NX10G                     NVARCHAR2(25)   
LINK_ID_1X10G                     NVARCHAR2(25)   
SPAN_ID_1X10G                     NVARCHAR2(25)   
LINK_ID_1X1G                      NVARCHAR2(25)   
SPAN_ID_1X1G                      NVARCHAR2(25)   
LINK_STATUS                       NVARCHAR2(30)   
LINK_RFE_DATE                     TIMESTAMP(6)    
NLD_POP_PATH1                     NVARCHAR2(25)   
NLD_POP_PATH2                     NVARCHAR2(25)   
EPC_PATH1                         NVARCHAR2(25)   
EPC_PATH2                         NVARCHAR2(25)   
LINK_RFE_PLAN                     TIMESTAMP(6)    
LINK_RFE_ACT                      TIMESTAMP(6)    
LINK_RFE_FCST                     TIMESTAMP(6)    
LAUNCH_MRO                        NVARCHAR2(50)   
LAUNCH_FRO                        NVARCHAR2(50)   
GLOBALID                          CHAR(38)        
JIOCENTERNAME                     NVARCHAR2(255)  
JIOCENTERCODE                     NVARCHAR2(10)   
JIOCENTER_RJID                    NVARCHAR2(10)   
LOGICAL_LINK_ID                   NVARCHAR2(25)   
LM_PARENT_ID                      NVARCHAR2(25)   
INTRACITY_PHASE                   NVARCHAR2(25)   
OLD_SPAN_ID                       NVARCHAR2(21)   
LM_CONNECTIVITY_TYPE              NVARCHAR2(20)   
PARENTEASTAG1SAPID                NVARCHAR2(18)   
PARENTWESTAG1SAPID                NVARCHAR2(18)   
POST_DATE                         TIMESTAMP(6)    
SURVEYSPANID_1                    NVARCHAR2(21)   
SURVEYSPANID_2                    NVARCHAR2(21)   
BLOWINGSPANID_2ND_DUCT            NVARCHAR2(21)   
BLOWINGSPANID_3RD_DUCT            NVARCHAR2(21)   
BLOWING_DUCT_COLOUR               NVARCHAR2(15)   
OLD_INTRACITY_LINK_ID             NVARCHAR2(15)   
HOTO_DONE_DATE                    TIMESTAMP(6)    
HOTO_DONE                         NVARCHAR2(50)   
SHAPE                             SDE.ST_GEOMETRY 
SDE_STATE_ID                      NUMBER
```

DESC Table 2:- R4G_APPDEV.plannedroute_evw

```
Name                     Null?    Type           
------------------------ -------- -------------- 
IID                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)   
PROJECT_PHASE                     VARCHAR2(20)   
NETWORK_CATEGORY                  VARCHAR2(50)   
NETWORK_TYPE                      NUMBER         
ROUTE_NAME                        VARCHAR2(200)  
LINK_ID                           VARCHAR2(25)   
SPAN_ID                           VARCHAR2(25)   
SPAN_NAME                         VARCHAR2(200)  
PARENT_LINK_ID                    VARCHAR2(25)   
SCOPE_CATEGORY                    VARCHAR2(25)   
FROM_FACILITY_LAT                 NUMBER         
FROM_FACILITY_LONG                NUMBER         
TO_FACILITY_LAT                   NUMBER         
TO_FACILITY_LONG                  NUMBER         
FROM_FACILITY                     VARCHAR2(25)   
TO_FACILITY                       VARCHAR2(25)   
LENGTH                            NUMBER         
JIO_STATE_CODE                    VARCHAR2(4)    
JIO_STATE_NAME                    VARCHAR2(200)  
STATE_CODE                        VARCHAR2(4)    
STATE_NAME                        VARCHAR2(200)  
CITY_CODE                         VARCHAR2(4)    
CITY_NAME                         VARCHAR2(200)  
FROM_CITY_NAME                    VARCHAR2(200)  
TO_CITY_NAME                      VARCHAR2(200)  
FROM_CITY_CODE                    VARCHAR2(4)    
TO_CITY_CODE                      VARCHAR2(4)    
NO_OF_CROSSING                    NUMBER         
TYPE_OF_CROSSING                  VARCHAR2(100)  
EXECUTING_MP                      VARCHAR2(50)   
STATUS                            VARCHAR2(40)   
DATE_ROUTE_RELEASED               DATE           
LAST_EDITED_USER                  VARCHAR2(100)  
LAST_EDITED_DATE         NOT NULL DATE           
INTRACITY_LINK_ID                 VARCHAR2(25)   
WORK_ORDER_NAME                   VARCHAR2(50)   
WORK_ORDER_STATUS_CODE            VARCHAR2(20)   
WORKFLOW                          VARCHAR2(20)   
LAST_EDITED_USER_REMARKS          VARCHAR2(1000) 
OBJECTID                 NOT NULL NUMBER(38)     
REVISION                          NUMBER         
TND_SCOPE_LENGTH                  NUMBER(20,2)   
BLOWING_SCOPE_LENGTH              NUMBER(20,2)   
SAP_ID                            VARCHAR2(20)   
LASTMILE_ID                       VARCHAR2(20)
```

Please let me know on how to update it.

**Note ** Table 1 unique column is `OBJECTID` and in table 2 it is `IID`

**UPDATE**

I started writing my procedure like below for comparing one column. Now I want to loop it for every records and if find any difference then update it. How to do it

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_CHK_PLNDRT_ASSMST AS 
VACTUALLEN nvarchar2(50);
VLENGTH nvarchar2(50);

BEGIN

SELECT ACTUALLENGTH into VACTUALLEN from R4G_APPDEV.plannedroute_evw
UNION ALL
select LENGTH into VLENGTH from ASSIGNED_ROUTE_MASTER;

  NULL;
END PROC_CHK_PLNDRT_ASSMST;
```

Comment: ok will try first and then update here accordingly!!

Comment: Which database do you use? MySQL or Oracle? Also, try to make it simple. Posting tables with zillion columns doesn't help.

Comment: @Littlefoot I use oracle.. sure will do that too

Comment: @Littlefoot: Pls look at my update, is it OK.. any guide me for further help

Comment: @RiggsFolly: can u pls check my updated question which I tried.. please suggest how can I achieve it. !!

Answer (score 1):

The way I understood it, you don't actually need to compare column-to-column and do the update if something's different - update it unconditionally (makes the "procedure" simpler). It means that you don't have to use PL/SQL at all as `merge` handles it at SQL level.

Tables' descriptions are different and I don't know which column from `plannedroute_evw` maps to which column in `assigned_route_master`. But, if you do, you'll easily complete the following `merge` statement.

Here's how:

```
merge into assigned_route_master b
  using plannedroute_evw a
  on (a.objectid = b.iid)
  when matched then update set
    b.length    = a.actual_length,
    b.city_code = a.city_code,
    <here you should map all columns between these two tables>
;
```

Comment: if the values of both column is same then it will update or when the values are different then it will update ?

Comment: It will update, regardless of whether values are different or not.

Comment: ohh, I just to update when values are **DIFFERENT**. Not in case when values are **SAME**

Comment: What difference does it make? If A.LENGTH = 10 and B.LENGTH = 10 and you update B.LENGTH to 10 (again), nothing will change (but query will be way simpler).

Comment: But what I want is, IF A = 10(Table 1) and B = 5 (Table 2). Then In this case , I want to update B = 10 (Table 2) with the values from Table 1.

Comment: Exactly. That MERGE will do it.

Comment: ok, then Fine.. this is what I was expecting. Will update you after checking. For now upvoting it +1